# Android application background not full screen

Tags: android

On some activities, the background is perfect, and on others is not. In the first picture, there is a white space on the right side. The second picture has a well-placed background. Many activities that have a well-placed background, the background is not constrained (I don't know how?). I have read and tried many possible solutions, ex. I changed implementation in dependencies in build.gradle, but it does not work. In addition are the pictures that show my problem. Any help is welcome.

[image]

[image]

XML for the first picture:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_width="132dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp" android:id="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498" app:backgroundTint="#4C9E45" android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="411dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@drawable/pineapple_blurred" android:id="@+id/imageView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="33dp"/>
    <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="208dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="36dp" android:progress="14"
    />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="369dp"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:text="Enter your username and password:"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:textColor="#517528" android:textSize="28sp"
            android:gravity="center" android:textStyle="bold" android:id="@+id/usernamePassText"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.619"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/usernameText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:hint="Username" android:textColorHint="#303030" android:textColor="#555555"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp" android:layout_marginStart="70dp" android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="70dp" android:textSize="22sp" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usernamePassText" android:layout_marginTop="55dp"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/passwordText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:hint="Password" android:textColorHint="#555555" android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp" android:layout_marginRight="70dp" android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" android:textSize="22sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/usernameText" android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/fillInTheBlanks"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordText" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.229"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_marginStart="30dp" android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="253dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp" android:id="@+id/passwordConstraint"
            android:textColor="#E20000" android:textSize="18sp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordText"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.443"
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML for the second picture:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="533dp"
            android:layout_height="621dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/avocado_blurred" android:id="@+id/imageView37"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="135dp"
            android:layout_height="82dp" android:id="@+id/recipesMenu5"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profileMenu" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            android:onClick="recipesActivity"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="135dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp" android:id="@+id/profileMenu6"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:onClick="myProfileActivity"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="67dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_profile_kremovo"
            android:id="@+id/imageView40"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profileMenu6"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profileMenu6"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profileMenu6" android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="131dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp" android:id="@+id/homeMenu5"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/profileMenu"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    />
    <TextView
            android:text="Home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/homeMenuText7"
            android:textColor="@color/white" android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/homeMenu5" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/homeMenu5"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="My profile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/homeMenuText9"
            android:textColor="#DEDFBE" android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profileMenu6"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profileMenu6"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="Recipes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/homeMenuText10"
            android:textColor="#DEDFBE" android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/recipesMenu5" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_belo" android:id="@+id/imageView39"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/homeMenu5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/homeMenu5" android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="Glass size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/glassSizeText"
            android:textSize="25sp" android:textColor="#517528"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homeSettingsText" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" android:layout_marginStart="40dp" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="83dp"
            android:text="Home settings"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:textColor="#517528" android:textSize="35sp"
            android:gravity="center" android:textStyle="bold" android:id="@+id/homeSettingsText"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="49dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" android:id="@+id/imageView25"
            android:onClick="back" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:layout_marginRight="320dp" android:layout_marginEnd="320dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="62dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/kapa_krem" android:id="@+id/imageView47"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/recipesMenu5" android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: please share the xml

Comment: Do share your XML files

Comment: I just posted the XML files.

Comment: These problems are usually due to the use of inappropriate wallpapers. I suggest changing the background image or resizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for that, I tried the backgrounds on different smartphones and figured out that the images have gaps or being warped.

You can easily avoid that using a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` instead of an `ImageView`. It is obviously made for backgrounds. Just replace your `ImageView` with that:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_image"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

As you can see, you set the `drawable` as the `background` of the `Layout`.

**My result:**

[image: Result]

In addition I uploaded my [project](https://workupload.com/file/xJSHHyMPbhZ) to try it out as reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same result as before.

Comment: It worked as you can see. Check your gradle version. I think there is something wrong. I will send you the whole code later to copy paste.

Comment: I am using gradle 6.7.1, maybe that is the problem?